# Filtering CassandraRepository by multiple fields dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I need to filter on multiple fields of an entity dynamically when searching the CassandraRepository.

Specifically, there are multiple String fields of the entity. The user can indicate which (if any) of these fields they want to match a specified Regular expression (e.g., ".*").

However, it looks like CassandraRepository doesn't provide support for JpaSpecificationExecutor, which is what resources online typically suggest using for this purpose, giving the following issue:

```
Could not create query for public abstract Page JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll(Specification, Pageable)! Reason: Page queries are not supported. Use a Slice query.
```

What is the appropriate way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the research I have done, the closest you can get is creating your own CQL Query String based on the inputs provided, and executing them on a `CassandraOperations` Object that you can autowire into the necessary class.